# Azure B2C Python SDK - Failing to access resource with "Access Token missing or malformed."

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I am attempting to leverage the Azure Python SDK using the GraphRBAC APIs to talk to my Azure B2C/AD users and roles.

I can use direct REST calls to get properly configured access tokens and call endpoints like this:

```
token_url: str = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_domain_name}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
my_credentials = {
    'client_id': my_client_id,
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'client_secret': my_secret,
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
}
response = requests.post(token_url, data = my_credentials)

users_url: str = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/'
response_data = response.json()
auth_headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {response_data['access_token']}"}
response = requests.get(users_url, headers=auth_headers)
```

Success!

Now, since I KNOW I have the security roles and scopes correct via the above test, I MUST be doing something boneheaded with the Azure Python SDK.  There are scant SDK docs, but here is the code I am trying to do the same thing, but with the SDK:

NOTE: The .default scope is INVALID when used with the resource field of the credentials below.  I tested it.

```
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id=my_client_id,
    secret=my_secret,
    resource="https://graph.microsoft.com/",
    tenant=my_tenant_name
)
graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
   credentials,
   my_tenant_id
)
users: UserPaged = graphrbac_client.users.list()
u: User = None
for u in users:
    print(u.display_name)
```

The above code fails with an exception like this executing the line of code where we call "for u in users" -- which basically calls next() on users:

> Exception has occurred: GraphErrorException       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)
> Access Token missing or malformed.
> File "/Users/{snip}/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/graphrbac/operations/users_operations.py", line 158, in internal_paging

I tried the above and I expected the same results via the SDK as I got via the REST endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

`MS Graph API` uses the endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

The `azure.graphrbac` package uses the legacy (soon to be deprecated) `Azure AD Graph API`, which uses the endpoint `https://graph.windows.net`. This package doesn't support the use of `MS Graph API`.

If you want to continue using this package:

- Update your `resource` to `https://graph.windows.net`
- You'll need to assign the appropriate `Azure AD Graph` API permission under the **App Registration**. If you try to do this in the portal, you'll see that `Azure AD Graph` is listed as a **Legacy API** and can't be selected, so you'll need to assign the permission programmatically.

**Reference**

[Azure Active Directory Graph libraries for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/microsoft-graph?view=azure-python)

[migrate GraphRbacManagementClient to Microsoft Graph](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/12513)

[Unable to authenticate to Azure GraphRBAC using DefaultAzureCredential OR CredentialWrapper](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/14022)

Comment: You are totally correct.  Thank you so much.  I was being boneheaded.  Definitely got trapped by the doc confusion/transition over at MS between MS Graph and Azure AD.  And newness of MS Graph python sdk and docs.  

I am sticking with good ol rest and direct token management for now.